# Reading file right outside jar

Tags: java, jar

So I have a .jar file in a folder and I have some input files in that folder. However, the program looks for the file in the home folder (several layers up). I want it obviously to read it from the folder that it's in but I don't want to be explicit about the file path to *my* folder because other people won't necessarily put their .jar file in the same spot.

Is there a way to read a file directly outside of the jar file? If not, is there a way to do this without hard-coding the file path?

edit:

here's the code. It just checks if the input files exist.

```
package main;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by chris on 12/1/15.
 * Control class that will be run when the jar is run.
 */
public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (!(new File("settings.txt").exists())) {
            start.run();
        }
        if (!(new File("api_key.txt").exists())) {
            alert.display("Make your api_key.txt please.");
        } else {
            gatherData.run();
        }
    }
}
```

edit 2:
I've tried adding relative references with "./" at the beginning but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you mean any path in filesystem?

Comment: Yes. So on my desktop, I have a folder on it containing a jar file and input files. But I want the program to work if the folder is somewhere else too.

Comment: I think you have hard coded the path.
Can you post code here?

Comment: I've added the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can rely on your .jar file being on the file system, you can get the absolute path of it by

```
new File(run.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

which can result in a `SecurityException` if a `SecurityManager` is present and not allowing this.

Another possibility would be to use

```
(new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))).getAbsolutePath();
```

The folder of the jar file can then be obtained using `getParentFile()`

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you are trying to access a file right in the same folder as that of the .jar file.

This can easily be done using the relative URL. By relative URL, I meant using
`new File("./settings.txt")`, this searches for the file in the folder same as that of the running .jar file. however you can use `"../settings.txt"` to look for the file one folder up.

`"./"` refers same directory `"../"` refers one directory up.

Comment: Even after that, it can't find the files... I don't know what's going on with it. I've tried "../" and "./" and all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ./ before file names.

Comment: It is not true. Because the working directory can be different like the place of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR files not neccesarly load from file system, and when loaded from file system can be any directory where the application start from - so relative path is not a good idea. The JAR files can from other types of source not only FileSystem, because it can be stream. I think the best way if there is a system parameter where you can pass the directory or working directory when you start the JAR file.