# Reading xml file outside jar in java

Tags: java, file

I need to read an xml file which is outside the jar.I don't want to use relative path. It's an absolute path on unix box. As far as I understand, I guess there are 2 ways:-
1) Change the manifest file of jar and add that location in the classpath. In this case can I use getResource()?
2) Hardcode the path in getResourceAsStream(). My path is going to be something like this "/usr/local/folder1/folder2/".I read that I can't use getResource() for anything outside classpath and I need to use getResourceAsStream().

Which of these ways is a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read properties file outside JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108412/reading-file-right-outside-jar)

Comment: above link doesn't answer the specific question that I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both `getResourceAsStream` and `getResource` are dependent on the paths visible to the class loader that loads your class or the bootstrap class. If you want to use absolute paths, just use `FileInputStream`.

`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/folder1/folder2/myxml.xml");`